# Putting the WordPress Loop into a class

Tags: class, php, wordpress

I am trying to build a framework essentially for WordPress Developers to help develop Themes and Theme Frameworks more efficiently and faster.

How ever, I am having a small issue by putting the wordpress loop into a class, this is what I have:

```
class AisisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop{

    protected $_options;

    public function __construct($options = null){
        if(isset($options)){
            $this->_options = $options; 
        }
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function loop(){
        if(have_posts()){
            while(have_posts()){
                the_post();
                the_content();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the simplicity of the class for now. All you have to do is:

```
$loop = new AisisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop();
$loop->loop();
```

And you should see the list of posts.

How ever, it appears that posts do not appear. Is there something preventing the WordPress loop from working?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have problem with "scope". You will need to pass `$wp_query` into the class or grab it via `global`. I believe that just this would work but only for the global `$wp_query`:

```
public function loop(){
    global $wp_query;
    if(have_posts()){
        while(have_posts()){
            the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
}
```

Untested but I think the following should work either with the global `$wp_query` or by passing in some other query result set.

```
protected $wp_query;

public function __construct($wp_query = null, $options = null){
    if (empty($wp_query)) global $wp_query;
    if (empty($wp_query)) return false; // or error handling

    $this->wp_query = $wp_query;

    if(isset($options)){
        $this->_options = $options; 
    }
}

public function loop(){
    global $wp_query;
    if($this->wp_query->have_posts()){
        while($this->wp_query->have_posts()){
            $this->wp_query->the_post();
            the_content();
        }
    }
}
```

Fingers crossed on that one but I think it should work. No promises though.

Comment: One problem - that I can solve, If you declaring wp_query to be a global class level variable. that is assigning a global to a class leve variable, then you do not need the global $wp_query in the function loop. ALSO: echoing $loop->loop() also works.

Comment: `$wp_query` is already global. Put `var_dump($GLOBALS['wp_query']);` at the top of nearly any WordPress page. It is still sometimes necessary to access it with `global $wp_query`, or via the `$GLOBALS` array.

Comment: what I am saying is that if you are already instantiating it in the constructor and setting it to a class level variable you dont need the global deffinition in the method.

Comment: I see. No, you shouldn't, not in the second version. I should have removed that.

Answer (score -3):

The proper, clean answer:

```
<?php

class AisisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop{

    protected $_options;

    protected $_wp_query;

    public function __construct($options = null){
        global $wp_query;

        if(isset($options)){
            $this->_options = $options; 
        }

        if(null === $this->_wp_query){
            $this->_wp_query = $wp_query;
        }
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function loop(){
        if($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
            while($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
                $this->_wp_query->the_post();
                the_content();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no actually you didn't. look at your loop(){} compared to mine. also your constructor is a mess.

Comment: I actually posted two possible solutions. Maybe that is why you aren't following. My constructor does things yours doesn't. I explained that in my answer. That is hardly a mess. Fact is, the significant parts of what you posted-- the parts that make it work--  here came from my answer. You pasted my pieces of code into your apparently broken code and claimed it as an answer (removing one I left in accidentally). I am not going to continue this, but have fun with it. Glad I could help.