# _html returns an empty string?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I have run across a bizzar issue, in which I know is working as i expect it to in terms of the array values, yet the _html variable returns something like string(29) "       " which to my knowledge means 29 spaces, since spaces count as characters (feel free to correct me).

Any ways, the class:

```
<?php

class AisisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop{

    protected $_options;

    protected $_wp_query;

    protected $_html = '';

    public function __construct($options = array()){
        global $wp_query;

        if(isset($options)){
            $this->_options = $options; 
        }

        if(null === $this->_wp_query){
            $this->_wp_query = $wp_query;
        }
    }

    public function init(){}

    public function loop(){
        if(isset($this->_options)){
            if(isset($this->_options['query'])){
                $this->_query_post($this->_options['query']);
            }elseif(isset($this->_options['type']) && $this->_options['type'] == 'single'){
                $this->_single_post();
            }else{
                $this->_general_wordpress_loop();
            }
        }else{
            $this->_general_wordpress_loop();
        }
    }

    protected function _general_wordpress_loop(){
        if($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
            while($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
                $this->_wp_query->the_post();
                the_excerpt();
            }
        }
    }

    protected function _query_post($query){
        $empty_query = $this->_wp_query;
        $wp_query = new WP_Query($query);

        if($wp_query->have_posts()){
            while($wp_query->have_posts()){
                $wp_query->the_post();
                the_excerpt();
            }
        }

        next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries'); 
        previous_posts_link('Newer Entries &raquo;');

        $wp_query = $empty_query;
    }

    protected function _single_post(){
        if($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
            while($this->_wp_query->have_posts()){
                $this->_wp_query->the_post();

                if(isset($this->_options['wrapper'])){
                    $this->_html .= '<div ';

                    if(isset($this->_options['wrapper']['class'])){
                        $this->_html .= 'class="'.$this->_options['wrapper']['class'].'"';
                    }elseif(isset($this->_options['wrapper']['id'])){
                        $this->_html .= 'class="'.$this->_options['wrapper']['id'].'"';
                    }

                    $this->_html .= ' >';
                }

                if(isset($this->_options['title_header'])){
                    $this->_html .= '<'.$this->_options['title_header'].'>';
                    the_title();
                    $this->_html .= '</'.$this->_options['title_header'].'>';
                }else{
                    the_title();
                }

                $this->_html .= '<a href="'.get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )).'">'.the_author_meta('display_name').'</a>';
                the_date();
                if(isset($this->_options['image'])){
                    if(isset($this->_options['size']) && isset($this->_options['args'])){
                        the_post_thumbnail($this->_options['image']['size'], $this->_options['image']['args']);
                    }else{
                        the_post_thumbnail('medium');
                    }
                }

                the_content();

                if(isset($this->_options['wrapper'])){
                    $this->_html .= '</div>';
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

the function to focus on is the _single_post() function. To instantiate and use this class we do the following:

```
$array = array(
    'wrapper' => array(
        'class' => 'span12'
    ),
    'title_header' => 'h1',
    'image' => array(
        'size' => 'type',
        'args' => array(
            'align' => 'centered', 
            'class' => 'thumbnail marginBottom20 marginTop20'
        )
    ),
    'type' => 'single'
);

$loop = new AisisCore_Template_Helpers_Loop($array);
$loop->loop();
```

So as you can see we set a wrapper div, a title_header, image attributes and a type of single. The problem is, I get into each *if statement where I am like if this is a wrapper and the class key is set with a value..* but the $this->_html returns empty.

when I var_dump($this->_html); I get an empty string. One might ask "are you getting into where your doing $this->_html .= 'some content'; ? and the answer is yes I am, how ever the string seems empty.

so I turn to you guys to help me see what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: I'd wager a guess that it's printing out fine, but the HTML tags are rendering as... HTML. Tried checking the source of the page?

Comment: if it was id see h1 tags, p tags and other associated tags in the source, except i DONT. hence the posting here.

Comment: No need to be defensive. You hadn't stated that you checked the source, so it was worth asking.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14651913/putting-the-wordpress-loop-into-a-class/14653397#comment20478505_14653397

Comment: this is not related in any way shape or form. please stop causing drama

Answer (score 0):

Well, all the places where you're calling things like `the_title()` and `the_author_meta('display_name')` and `the_post_thumbnail` and `the_content()` are wrong. Those cause output, they don't return strings.

And also, without knowing where you're var_dumping the data, it's impossible to say what the expected result would be.